# NGINX Rewrite url without redirect

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a url like this:

http://exemple.org/Connexion.php

I would like to have :
http://exemple.org/se_connecter.html. 
But there's no file called `se_connecter.html`, I just want a rewrite, not a redirect.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question isn't quite clear. Would you like for users to have the address in their browser changed without them being redirected to a new address, or would you like the contents of a file called `se_connected.html` shown on `http://exemple.org/Connexion.php`?

Comment: i would like for users to have the address in their browser changed without them being redirect to a new adress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking isn't possible in HTTP. You might be able to do it using a hack in javascript (e.g. using `history.replaceState`) but I'd recommend against it.